# Get the color name from the bootstrap color picker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker, jquery-color

The bootstrap color picker works perfectly as I wanted. Here is the link I used to perform the color picker
https://farbelous.github.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/

The input box are generated into hex and rgb value. However, I want to know the color name. As there is no option for the name in the format of the color

```
picker as shown below
 $('#cp2').colorpicker({
format: 'colorname' // this option doesn't work
});
```

How can I achieve this in the bootstrap color picker.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that retrieving the color name is available. As stated in the documentation you posted, the only options for `format` are

- hex
- rgb
- rgba
- false - (automatically detected format)

If you really want a name associated to a color, a website called [ColourLovers](http://www.colourlovers.com) has an [API](http://www.colourlovers.com/api) for this. The name returned in a request won't necessarily correspond to a color understood by an HTML parser, but nevertheless, it's something.